# How can I quickly count the maximum number of consecutive single characters in a string?

Tags: string, perl, replace, count, tr

I have a string similar to:  *but much longer*

```
my $a = "000000001111111111000000011111111111111111111111111111111";
```

I am counting the number of "1"'s with:

```
my $total_1_available = $a =~ tr/1//;
```

And that works amazingly well and is really FAST.

HOWEVER, I also wish to count (in a fast way), the total number of consecutive 1's in a row. The MAX COUNT of "1's" consecutively.

IN the example above, it would return the count of:

```
11111111111111111111111111111111
```

As this is the maximum in a row.

So, I end up with the TOTAL_COUNT and also the TOTAL_CONSECUTIVE_COUNT.

I have it working with a REGEXP which basically replaces the 1's and then counts what was replaced and loops around...which actually is totally fine and works... but it doesn't "feel" right.

Ideally I don't want to replace the string at all as I am looking for the max consecutive count.

But, I know in Perl this probably isn't the fastest or cleanest way.

Could you teach me a better way please and increase my learning?

AS requested this is my current code:

```
 my $a= "0110011001101111";
 my $total_1_available = $a =~ tr/1//;
 print "Total number of 1's = $total_1_available\n";

 my $max_c = 0;
 while ( $a=~s/(1+)/ / ) {
   $max_c = length($1) if length($1) > $max_c;
 }
 print "Consecutive count   = $max_c\n";
```

And FINAL CODE:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Benchmark ':all';
use String::Random;

## We test 525,600 as this is the length of the string.
## Actually each 0 or 1 represents a minute of the year.
## And these represent engineer minues available in a 24 hr / 365 day year.
## And there are lots and lots of engineers.
## Hence my wish to improve the performance and I wish to thank everyone whom responded.

## there are a lot more 0's than 1's so hack to sort of simulate
my $test_regex = '[0][0][0][0][0][0-1][0-1][0-1][0-1][0-1]' x 52560;
my $pass       = String::Random->new;
my $string     = $pass->randregex($test_regex);

cmpthese(-1, {
    org  => sub { my $max = 0; while ($string =~ /(1+)/g) { my $len = length($1); if ($max < $len) { $max = $len } } },
    hack => sub { my $match = ""; while ($string =~ /(${match}1+)/g) { $match = $1; } length $match }
});

#                BLOWN AWAY !!!!!!
#                BLOWN AWAY !!!!!!
#                BLOWN AWAY !!!!!!
#                BLOWN AWAY !!!!!!
```

Comment: My string is just 1's and 0's. Yes.  the tr gives me the OVERALL TOTAL count which I need and this is good.  I would also like the get the MAX number of 1's in a row in the entire string if that makes sense..  i.e. 001110011   would return 3 where tr gives 5.

Comment: You should not use `$a` (or `$b`) because it is a predefined variable used by `sort()`.

Comment: Try my new solution on one of your long strings and check the result with your original solution, see how it works.

Comment: I will check performance and report back. Some interesting options.

Comment: Don't seach a 'cleaner' way in pearl! If it's correct, fast and readable, then it's OK. If you think all should be fine and clean, then use something like c#. There it must!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remarkable speed improvements can be made with a dynamic regex. We can use a variable to store the max length string, then search for a string that is that long, plus one or more. The theory being that we only need to look for strings longer than the one we already have.

I used a solution that looks like this

```
sub hack {
    my $match = "";                        # original search string
    while ($string =~ /(${match}1+)/g) {   # search for $match plus 1 or more 1s
        $match = $1;                       # when found, change to new match
    }
    length $match;                         # return max length
}
```

And compared it to the original method described by the OP, with the following result

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Benchmark ':all';

my $string = '0100100101111011010010101101101110101011111111101010100100100001011101010100' x 10_000;

cmpthese(-1, {
    org  => sub { my $max = 0; while ($string =~ /(1+)/g) { my $len = length($1); if ($max < $len) { $max = $len } } },
    hack => sub { my $match = ""; while ($string =~ /(${match}1+)/g) { $match = $1; } length $match }
});
```

Output:

```
       Rate    org   hack
org  7.31/s     --   -99%
hack 1372/s 18669%     --
```

Which seems astonishingly high, 19000% faster. It makes me think I've made a mistake, but I can't think what that would be. Maybe I am missing something in the regex machine internals, but this would be quite the improvement on the original solution.

Comment: yes, there is always a better way with perl which is why I like it so much. I will report back.

Comment: For the input used, your solution performs the loop four times. `org` has something like 250,000 passes. Each of those passes includes a slow regex engine start

Comment: @TLP Re "*Which seems astonishingly high*", Just wait till you read my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67326319/589924) and find out that your solution is 33% faster than my (naïve) XS solution!

Comment: @TLP I knew there was a better way and you found it.  Definitely learnt a lot.

Comment: @Mark Arnold You're welcome. It was an inspiring problem.

Comment: @ikegami I was wondering if the regex engine somehow optimizes the search with a predictable repetition in the input (using x), which is why I asked Mark to use it with his input. I'm curious to get a randomized long string to try it with tonight.

Answer (score 3):

For short strings, the following is faster than all previously-presented solutions:

```perl
use List::Util qw( max );

max 0, map length, split /[^1]+/, $s
```

```
          Rate  hack  sort   org   max  mxsp    xs
hack   76879/s    --  -12%  -34%  -37%  -48%  -98%   <-- TLP
sort   87664/s   14%    --  -24%  -28%  -41%  -98%   <-- Jim Davis
org   115660/s   50%   32%    --   -6%  -22%  -98%   <-- OP
max   122504/s   59%   40%    6%    --  -17%  -98%   <-- Jim Davis
mxsp  147867/s   92%   69%   28%   21%    --  -97%   <-- ikegami (above)
xs   4950278/s 6339% 5547% 4180% 3941% 3248%    --   <-- ikegami (below)
```

Benchmark code:

```perl
use Benchmark qw( cmpthese );

my $string = ( '01001001011110110100101011011011101010'
             . '11111111101010100100100001011101010100' );

cmpthese(-3, {
    org  => sub { my $max = 0; while ($string =~ /(1+)/g) { my $len = length($1); if ($max < $len) { $max = $len; } } },
    hack => sub { my $match = ""; while ($string =~ /(${match}1+)/g) { $match = $1; } my $max = length($match); },
    sort => sub { my $max = ( sort { $b <=> $a } $string =~ /(1+)/g )[0]; },
    max  => sub { my $max = max 0, map length, $string =~ /(1+)/g; },
    mxsp => sub { my $max = max 0, map length, split /[^1]+/, $string; },
    xs   => sub { my $max = longuest_ones_count($string); },
});
```

---

That said, the fastest solution would involve XS. The following is my stab at it:

```c
IV longuest_ones_count(SV* sv) {
   IV max = 0;
   IV count = 0;

   // This code works whether the string is upgraded or downgraded.
   STRLEN len;
   char *s = SvPV(sv, len);
   while (len--) {
      if (*(s++) == '1') {
         ++count;
      }
      else if (count) {
         if (max < count)
            max = count;

         count = 0;
      }
   }

   if (max < count)
      max = count;

   return max;
}
```

One way of using it:

```perl
use 5.014;
use warnings;

use Inline C => <<'__';

...above code here...

__


say "$_: ", longuest_ones_count($_)
   for qw(
      0
      11111
      011111
      111110
      01110111110
      01111101110
   );
```

---

You saw this beat the other solutions out of the water for short strings. But you don't have short strings. For long strings, this is not as fast as TLP's version!!!

Same benchmark as above but using

```perl
my $string = ( '01001001011110110100101011011011101010'
             . '11111111101010100100100001011101010100' ) x 10_000;
```

```
       Rate   sort    org    max   mxsp     xs   hack
sort 8.61/s     --   -25%   -31%   -44%   -99%   -99%
org  11.6/s    34%     --    -8%   -24%   -99%   -99%
max  12.5/s    46%     9%     --   -18%   -99%   -99%
mxsp 15.3/s    77%    32%    22%     --   -99%   -99%  <-- ikegami (Perl)
xs   1031/s 11870%  8822%  8118%  6653%     --   -25%  <-- ikegami (XS)
hack 1366/s 15772% 11731% 10797%  8855%    33%     --  <-- TLP
```

Wow the regex engine is good! It can obviously be beat using XS (by eliminating the time needed to compile the pattern), but what's the point?

Comment: Nice review of all the solutions. For me, my sort solution was so slow I could not even include it in my benchmarks with longer strings. Hardware difference, I guess.

Comment: Also, OP mentions that most of the input will be zeroes, which would synergize with a split solution. Can it be combined with xs?

Comment: I am sure it could be sped up even further. :)  The answered solution represents a massive speed improvement combined with the simplicity of the original working example.  There is always a balance between optimization and technical implementation.  Thank you all.

Comment: @TLP mostly zeros helps your "hack" solution, actually.

Comment: @MarkArnold yeah, that's what I meant by the answer's last paragraph

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably do something like this:

```
use List::Util 'max';

my $string = '01011101100000111111001';

my $longest_run = max( 0, map { length } $string =~ /(1+)/g );
```

That fetches the length of each matched group of 1s and picks the largest.  Inserted a 0 so you don't get an `undef` if there aren't any.

```
$ perl -MList::Util=max \
  -E 'say $_, " ", max(0, map { length } /(1+)/g) for @ARGV' \
  0 1 00010110 011101111110100110

0 0
1 1
00010110 2
011101111110100110 6
```

Edit: @TLP's comment made me curious, because I liked the `sort` solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use v5.16;
use warnings;

use Benchmark ':all';
use List::Util 'max';

my $string = '0100100101111011010010101101101110101011111111101010100100100001011101010100';

cmpthese(1_000_000, {
    sort => sub { my $x =    (  sort { $b <=> $a } $string =~ /(1+)/g)[0] },
    max  => sub { my $x = max(0, map { length    } $string =~ /(1+)/g)    },
});
```

resulted in:

```
        Rate sort  max
sort 84890/s   --  -9%
max  93023/s  10%   --
```

Perhaps longer/shorter test strings would yield different results?

Comment: Since this is a performance question, it might be nice to benchmark how `max()` compares to a regular `sort()`.

Comment: Interesting!  I tried it with a 10k string over 50k iterations, and got `sort 724/s, max 926/s (+28%)`.  I'd expect `sort` to be doing more comparisons, but `max` only makes one pass -- although it's doing a `length` on each.  Hmm!

Comment: I am getting that the original solution (using only 1 `length()`) is 19% faster than max, and 61% faster than sort. Using `x 1_000` on your string.

Comment: The ultimate hack would be if you could dynamically search for strings longer than the current max, e.g. `/(1{$max,}/g`. Which I guess you could sort of do by just changing the string you are looking for, but then you could not use `/g` modifier, but would have to hack into storing the index of the match, `$+[0]` perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Perl allows you to create hashes on the fly, you can use this to do counting.

loop through each charecter of $a using that letter to increment the contents of the hash. at the end of the loop you will have a hash with keys containing each letter and values containing the count for each one.

```
foreach $letter (split //, $a) {
    if $letter eq $last { 
        $consecutive_count{$letter}++
    } else {
        if ($consecutive_count{$letter} > $consecutive_runs{$letter})
             $consecutive_runs{$letter} = $consecutive_count{$letter};
             $consecutive_count{$letter} = 0;
        }
    }   
    $counts{$letter}++;
    $last = $letter;    
}

foreach my $key (keys %counts) {
    print "$key occured $counts{$letter} times";
    print "longest consecutive run for $key was $consecutive_runs{$key}";
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like it is solving the question of how to count the max number of 1s in a row.

Comment: yeah i updated it to add the consecutives

Comment: have a look at B::DeParse , its an internal module that can export a code version of the perls internal optimised representation of your code.  this can help you see how your code is being run and can often show you how a slight error is being misenterpreted or how code seems to be ignored.
https://perldoc.perl.org/B::Deparse